# Unable able to create react app using next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I'm trying to create a react app I'm unable to do it. The documentation is different now. It's asking to install it through next js. And when I installed it it shows the following error

```
ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
t\server\next-server.js:175:9)
    at NextServer.createServer (C:\Users\srava\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:179:24)
    at async C:\Users\srava\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:200:31
    at async NextServer.prepare (C:\Users\srava\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:161:24)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\srava\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\render-server.js:128:17) {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

Please someone solve this error

Comment: Please take the [tour]. This is not a code-writing service. See also [ask]

Comment: Kindly checkout https://stackoverflow.com/tour for `how to ask question`

Answer (score 1):

Recently `npx create-react-app my-app` was [depricated](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13072)

You can follow these alternatives of `create-react-app`

1. [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/): `npx create-next-app`
2. [Remix](https://remix.run/): `npx create-remix`
3. [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/): `npx create-gatsby`

Answer (score 0):

update Next.js and related dependencies: If you are using an older version of Next.js or any related packages, it's possible that the issue you're encountering has already been fixed in a newer version.